# UWP title bar close button size

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

How can the size, especially **width**, of the close button (or titlebar buttons in general) be retrieved in Windows universal apps?

One of our UI elements displays a full-height panel on the right which has to have the exact same width as the close button:

[Close button not aligned with SplitView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLurZ.png)

Answer (score 4):

The [`CoreApplicationViewTitleBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplicationviewtitlebar) has the necessary properties for this purpose.

To learn how to use these properties correctly, go to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar#system-caption-buttons) page which is about the correct way of using System Caption Buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There are only `SystemOverlayLeftInset` and `SystemOverlayRightInset`, though. They specify the whole left or right area reserved for system caption buttons. Unfortunately this doesn't give any information about the size of a **single** of those caption buttons.

Comment: I think they are all same in size